# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. occurred

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

I installed the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps package for my project.
I have this code in the XAML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
             x:Class="AppXamarin.Pages.MapPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <maps:Map  x:Name="map" ></maps:Map>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I keep getting this exception when launching the application!

What is causing the exception?

Comment: you need to look at the InnerException property to get the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add initialization for `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` in `MainActivity.cs`.

Here:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


            // initialize for Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps    
            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState); 

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample you can refer: [XFGoogleMapSample](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/tree/master/)

You also need to create An Android API Key to use Google Map.

[how-to-use-google-maps-in-xamarin-forms](https://blog.bitbull.com/2017/02/13/how-to-use-google-maps-in-xamarin-forms/)